# Python String Between

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay I have been reading all over the web today and have not been able to find anything that truly works for this.

Here is what I have currently

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/PLUG:US'

sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

string2=sock.replace("data_values","show_1D")

print (string2[1]);
```

I am having trouble pulling the data in between the data_values area and the show_1D

This is the data of a stock and I am confused.

Thank You

I also have used this as a reference and the examples wont even work

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm
```

Comment: What do you get when you `print(string2)`? Also, no need for the semicolon.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, but it seems that you need `re.sub(r'data_values\s*(.*?)\s*show_1D', "\\1", sock)`

Comment: Devnull I am confused. All I need is the data between data_values and show_1D. I am trying what you gave me I might understand enough to get it to work. Also How come most of the examples I find out here dont work. Has python changed syntax in the recent years or something?

Comment: @user3375681 "Don't work" is vague. You are using Python 3 libraries and syntax. Make sure your examples are too. Python 2 to 3 had some syntax/library changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at what is being downloaded, you can see that the data is encoded in UTF-8.

Just add the `decode('UTF-8')` method to convert the download to something Python 3 can work with:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/PLUG:US'

sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
print(sock.count("data_values"), sock.count("show_1D"))
# 1 1
string2=sock.replace("data_values","show_1D")
print (string2.count("data_values"), string2.count("show_1D"))
# 0 2
```

While that may solve this one issue, *do use an HTML parser rather than simple regex's or string replaces to deal with XML and HTML* such as [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) among many others.